# On button click assign div inner html to input field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want is when someone click on button, set the phone number to input value. The block is a loop in which different email and phone number appears. if some one click in a specific block get the phone number from that block only. Thanks.

```
<div class="block">
     <div class="phone"><span>+1234567</span></div>
     <div class="email">
          <span>email@email.com</span>
          <button>CLick</button>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
     <div class="phone"><span>+7696686</span></div>
     <div class="email">
          <span>another@email.com</span>
          <button>CLick</button>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
     <div class="phone"><span>+897979877</span></div>
     <div class="email">
          <span>email2@email.com</span>
          <button>CLick</button>
     </div>
</div>
<input type="text" value="" id="phone">
```

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".block button").click(function() {
        var contents = jQuery(this).find(".phone span").text();
        jQuery("#phone").val(contents);
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**. You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @Sam Onela Thanks for the suggestion, really appreciated.

Comment: add your javascript that you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged jQuery so I'm assuming it's ok for you to receive an answer using jQuery. Try something similar to:

```
$('button').click(function(){
   var phoneNumber = $(this).closest('.phone').find('span').text();
});
```

Comment: @SajjadAhmad Good to hear. If this answer worked for you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.

Comment: i tried to accept your answer, but stack overflow is not allowing me because of reputation limit. I need at least 15 reputation to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(".block").each(function() {
        $(this).find('button').click(function(){
          var contents = $(this).parents('.block').find('.phone span').text();
          $("#phone").val(contents);
        });        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
     <div class="phone"><span>+1234567</span></div>
     <div class="email">
          <span>email@email.com</span>
          <button>CLick</button>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
     <div class="phone"><span>+7696686</span></div>
     <div class="email">
          <span>another@email.com</span>
          <button>CLick</button>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="block">
     <div class="phone"><span>+897979877</span></div>
     <div class="email">
          <span>email2@email.com</span>
          <button>CLick</button>
     </div>
</div>
<input type="text" value="" id="phone">
```

Comment: This is what i needed. Thank you.